# Android HttpPost request to server

Tags: android, sqlite, codeigniter, http-post

i want to send data from android SqLite database to my Codeigniter web App controller which take the post data and save it to MySql database
so i made buttn to make this sync task in android app and its code:

```
    public void syncAttendance(View v) {
    try
    {
    /** Retrieving data from database **/
    //use cursor to keep all data
    //cursor can keep data of any data type
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from mytable", null);
    int memNum = 1;
    //move cursor to first position
    c.moveToFirst();
    //fetch all data one by one
    do
    {
        //we can use c.getString(0) here
        //or we can get data using column index
        String memID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("memID"));
        String currTime = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("currTime"));
        String dayName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("dayName"));

        ////////////////////////////////////////

     // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/index.php/admin/attendance/scan_qr");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

      /**  try {**/
            // JSON data:
            json.put("memID", memID);
            json.put("currTime", currTime);
            json.put("dayName", dayName);

            JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
            postjson.put(json);

            // Post the data:
            httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            System.out.print(json);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // for JSON:
            if(response != null)
            {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                text = sb.toString();
            }

            //tv.setText(text);
 /**
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        **/
        //////////////////////////////////////////

        /** show confirmation toast **/

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, memNum + memID + currTime + dayName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        memNum ++;
        //move next position until end of the data
    }while(c.moveToNext());

    /** show confirmation toast **/
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Synchronization Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and the php codeigniter controller code is:

```
public function scan_qr()
{

        $json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
        var_dump($json);

        $data = json_decode($json);
        var_dump($data);

        $memID = $data->memID;
        $currTime = $data->currTime;
        $dayName = $data->dayName;
        $ma7abawy_year = 3;

        $data= array(
                        'member_id' => $memID,
                        //'points' => $points,
                        'presence_time' => $currTime,
                        //'event' => $eventname,
                        'event_date' => $dayName,
                        'ma7abawy_year' => $ma7abawy_year
                    );
        $this->db->insert('attendance',$data);

}
```

i have no exception but nothing is happened

any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: any reason you're passing your data in a header? Why not a conventional post name=value key pair?

Comment: how can do it from android ?? and was it is the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use **retrofit** (see [API docs](https://github.com/square/retrofit)) library to consume the service. Afterwards, see what you get back in the response and it will be a simple matter of saving the data to the sqlite3 db. See [example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for saving data.

Comment: thanks for your replay, I am a very newbie in java and android so i can't understand what you mean exactly, i want to let you know that my app is made for scanning academy members QR code for attendance and store the attendance in SQLite database to sync these data whenever the internet connection is available, i made the scanning, storing, retrieving  data successfully but i cant make the sync task to transfer these attendance data to MySQL database through my codeigniter web app